# Write two loops output in two columns in shell?

Tags: shell, awk

How can I write the following in an efficient way:

```
for j in {1..339};do
  for i in {1..427};do
    echo -e $j'\t'$i  >> ofile.txt
  done
done
```

Answer (score 3):

here is one alternative without explicit loops

```
join -j9 -t$'\t' <(seq 339) <(seq 427) | cut -f2- > ofile.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Move the redirection to the outer loop so `ofile.txt` is only opened once.

```
for j in {1..339}; do
  for i in {1..427}; do
    echo -e "$j\t$i"
  done
done >> ofile.txt
```

It is probably also better to use C-style for loops to prevent those curly braces from having to be expanded, though I haven't profiled it. That's a lesseroptimization.

```
for ((j = 1; j <= 339; ++j)); do
  for ((i = 1; i <= 427; ++i)); do
    echo -e "$j\t$i"
  done
done >> ofile.txt
```

Comment: `done > ofile.txt` might be more what the OP intended, but he didn't specify.

Answer (score 2):

*Karakfa*'s method, with no **cut**:

`join -j9 -o 1.1,2.1 -t$'\t' <(seq 339) <(seq 427) > ofile.txt`

Benchmarks, using **bash**'s builtin **time** command, just the 'real' number, (which varies somewhat from system to system, my CPU is about 4390 bogomips):

- **join** (*Karakfa-agc*):  .029s
- **join** (with **cut**, *Karakfa*):  .039s
- **my** (*Szilágyi*): .086s
- **perl** (*Osmanov*): .092s
- **awk** (*Morton*): .139s
- **dash** (*agc*): 1.159s
- **bash** (*Kugelman*): 2.153s
- **bash** (*Kayan* -- OP): 3.001s

Takeaway: **join** provides a 100x speedup.

Answer (score 2):

```
cat my.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main(n,s)int n; char **s;{
int i, j;
if(n!=3)exit(1);
for(i=1; i<=atoi(s[1]); i++)
  for(j=1; j<=atoi(s[2]); j++)
    printf("%4d %4d\n",i,j);
}

gcc my.c -o my

time ./my 339 427 >ofile.txt
real    0m0.035s
user    0m0.024s
sys 0m0.008s

cat karakfa_agc_solution
join -j9 -o 1.1,2.1 -t$'\t' <(seq 339) <(seq 427) > ofile.txt

time ./karakfa_agc_solution >ofile.txt
real    0m0.032s
user    0m0.012s
sys 0m0.008s

cat /proc/cpuinfo |grep bogo
bogomips    : 6629.54
```

I couldn't do faster code in C also.

Comment: Compiling that on my system (Intel Core i3-2330M) ran 2 or 3x slower than *join*.  Your box must have a different architecture or better default compiler settings -- perhaps there's some less relative benchmark tool out there.   Anyway this: `#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(n,s)int n; char **s;{
if(n!=3)exit(1);
int i, im=atoi(s[1]), j,jm=atoi(s[2]);
for(i=1; i<=im; i++)
  for(j=1; j<=jm; j++)
    printf("%-d\t%-d\n",i,j);
}` made it go about 30% faster...  Off to go look up the *join* source code now, see how they did it...

Comment: Checked source:  for output *join* uses *putchar()*, *fputs()*, and *fwrite()*.

Comment: My CPU: AMD Phenom(tm) II X2 560 Processor  (3.3GHz)

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -e '
for my $j (1..339) {
  for my $i (1..427) {
    print "$j\t$i\n";
  }
}
' > ofile.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'BEGIN {
    OFS="\t"
    for (j=1;j<=339;j++) {
      for (i=1;i<=427;i++) {
        print j, i
      }
    }
}' > ofile.txt
```

Also see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice

Answer (score 1):

POSIX shell, with **seq**:

```
#!/bin/dash
for j in `seq 339`;do
  for i in `seq 427`;do
    echo $j\\\t$i
  done
done > ofile.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a little bit faster C code with fwrite() function and with an ASCII code table (ref to @agc ).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define L 6                   // max digit

main(n,s)int n; char **s;{
unsigned int i, j, k, m1, m2, mx;
char *p;

if(n!=3){printf("Usage %s num1 num2\n", s[0]); exit(__LINE__);}
m1=atoi(s[1]); m2=atoi(s[2]);
if(!(m1*m2)|| strlen(s[1])>L|| strlen(s[2])>L)exit(__LINE__);

mx=m1>m2?m1:m2;              // max input num

// allocate and init ASCII code tbl for the bigest inp oper
if(!(p=(char *)malloc((mx+1)*(L+2))))exit(__LINE__);
if(!memset(p, ' ', (mx+1)*(L+2)))exit(__LINE__);
for(i=1; i<=mx; i++){
   for(j=i,k=L-1; j; j/=10,k--)p[i*(L+2)+k]=j%10+'0';
   p[i*(L+2)+L]='\t'; p[i*(L+2)+L+1]='\n';}

for(i=1; i<=m1; i++)         //print variants from ASCII tbl
  for(j=1; j<=m2; j++){
    fwrite(p+(L+2)*i, L+1, 1,stdout);
    fwrite(p+(L+2)*j, L+2, 1,stdout);}
}

gcc -o optf optf.c

time ./optf 339 427 >ofile.txt
real    0m0.010s
user    0m0.004s
sys 0m0.004s
bogomips    :6629
architecture:AMD Phenom(tm) II X2 560
```